# Help building pygtk application

Tags: packaging, deb, pygtk

This is my [application](https://github.com/umpirsky/revision-monitor).

It is created with quickly.

I would like to package it for Ubuntu now.

I tried to package it with uickly, but that [failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94168/package-pygtk-app-with-quickly-fails).

At first, I was trying to install it using [setup.py](https://github.com/umpirsky/revision-monitor/blob/master/setup.py). But it is only copied in python lib dir, no icon, no desktop file installed.

Then I tried to follow [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Python), but I ended up with package without icon and it was of bad quality, but most important of all, it does not use setup.py, and it was pretty complicated. I would like to automate packaging process

Can someone point me in the right direction, some examples of existing apps that have automated packaging etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(OP solved problem)*

That's right, I make it. it needs .bzr repo for build, for some reason. Thanks. – umpirsky Jan 17 at 14:13

Answer (score 0):

If you are using quickly, packaging should be as simple as typing:

```
quickly package
```

You can edit the file [revision-monitor.desktop.in](https://github.com/umpirsky/revision-monitor/blob/master/revision-monitor.desktop.in) to select an icon and a category, but it looks like you already did it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but that fails for some reason http://askubuntu.com/questions/94168/package-pygtk-app-with-quickly-fails That Loosks like desktop file and icons are not insalled on appropriate location when I run setup.py, so it should probably be updated with some code to install this files. Also, deb package should somehow run setup.py in order to get all this things installed.

Comment: They are in the same relative place than my only quickly project, and it packages. Has you modified the setup.py file?.

Comment: Hehum, I'm not sure about that. In order to be integrated into Unity desktop file and application should be copied to `/usr/share/` or sth like that. Icons to `/usr/share/icons...` and so on. No, I didn't it's pretty much similar to one from quickly template http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~quickly-committers/quickly/trunk/view/head:/data/templates/ubuntu-application/project_root/setup.py

Comment: Quickly will (at least it did for me) take care of that.

Comment: Take care of what, packaging application or copy icons, desktop file... to appropriate location when you run setup.py? If seconds, where is that piece of code in setup.py? How do you run setup.py?

Comment: I tried again and got `...................Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "/home/umpirsky/Projects/Python/revision-monitor/".
ERROR: can't create or update ubuntu package
ERROR: package command failed
Aborting
` so I guess I just need to fix bzr repo. Perhaps `bzr init` ?

Comment: That's right, I make it. it needs .bzr repo for build, for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: The deb that quickly creates includes the icons and the .desktop to the rigth place. It's likely not done in setup.py, but in whatever code quickly package executes.